# Ansible: check `When` before check for undefined variables

Tags: ansible

ansible 2.9.6

I have a list of hashes within `with_items`. And I put `when` as one of the items params.
So, the some items will be executed, some not. I don't want to declare or set defaults for the variables in skipped items. But i have "VAR_2 is undefined" error even for items that will not be executed.

Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: localtest
      template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: "{{ item.BASE_NAME }}-test.txt"
      when: "item.when"
      with_items:
        - { BASE_NAME: "{{VAR_1}}", when: "{{ variable_true }}" }
        - { BASE_NAME: "{{VAR_2}}", when: "{{ variable_false }}" }
        - { BASE_NAME: "{{VAR_3}}", when: "{{ variable_true }}" }
```

I don't want to use defaults, because I'm using this Play for the different hosts with different variables sets. And I need errors, when necessary variable (with when `true`  condition) is undeclared.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here is the reason of the [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) special variable, that you can use in Ansible with the `default` filter.

> By default Ansible requires values for all variables in a templated expression. However, you can make specific variables optional. For example, you might want to use a system default for some items and control the value for others. To make a variable optional, set the default value to the special variable `omit`

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional*</sup>

So you could do with a playbook like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: "{{ item.BASE_NAME }}-test.txt"
      when: "item.when"
      with_items:
        - BASE_NAME: "{{ VAR_1 | default(omit) }}"
          when: "{{ variable_true }}"
        - BASE_NAME: "{{ VAR_2 | default(omit) }}"
          when: "{{ variable_false }}"
        - BASE_NAME: "{{ VAR_3 | default(omit) }}"
          when: "{{ variable_true }}"
      vars: 
        variable_true: true
        variable_false: false
```

---

Another thing you could do, but, that, I, personally find less appealing, is to define only the name of your variables in your loop, then refer to the content of this variable using the [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9//plugins/lookup/vars.html) lookup.

So ending whit this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: "{{ lookup('vars', item.BASE_NAME) }}-test.txt"
      when: "item.when"
      with_items:
        - BASE_NAME: "VAR_1"
          when: "{{ variable_true }}"
        - BASE_NAME: "VAR_2"
          when: "{{ variable_false }}"
        - BASE_NAME: "VAR_3"
          when: "{{ variable_true }}"
      vars: 
        variable_true: true
        variable_false: false
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful explanation and good looking formatting. But not exactly for my case.
Looks like I missed main idea in my explanation. I need to keep warnings about not declared variables for the used items.
For example. I have  two hosts.
For the first one I need to deploy 1st and 3td  Databases with several prams.
For the second one I need to deploy 1st and 2nd Databases with several prams.
So. I am using one variable for deploy/not-deploy flag. It is Ok.
And several variables as a params. If I omit them, I may miss them for the deployments.